# Why ec2:Get* not in AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I found that the AWS managed policy `ReadOnlyAccess` has `ec2:Get*` permission, but `AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess` does not.

Why?

[image: AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess]
[image: ReadOnlyAccess]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be too worried about it.

The only `ec2:Get*` permissions are:

- GetConsoleOutput
- GetConsoleScreenshot
- GetHostReservationPurchasePreview
- GetLaunchTemplateData
- GetPasswordData
- GetReservedInstancesExchangeQuote

See: [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon EC2 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html)

The comment on `AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess` says: "Provides read only access to Amazon EC2 via the AWS Management Console."

I guess they were the only permissions needed for console access, or it could be an omission.